# How can I specify a sheet as range in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, range

I want to apply conditional formatting on a sheet. I used to do `Ctrl + A` and then apply the formatting, but when i insert new cells or rows, this isn't included in the formatting. As you can see in the picture below, you have to give a range.

[image: Conditional Formatting]

Is it possible to give the entire sheet as range and how to do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For MS Office 2007 and later, use

`1:1048576`

to select all cells in the entire worksheet.

For MS Office 2003 and earlier, use

`1:65536`

Comment: i thought there would be something like "worksheet" or something, but seems like there's not so i guess this will do. Thanks.

Comment: @djerry: You're welcome. If it was in VBA, there would be more options.

Comment: 1:1048576 means all rows from row 1 to row1048576. 1048576 is 2^20.

Comment: I suggest using absolute references for this instead, so your formulas can be copy/pasted/filled. Otherwise you'll end up with a #REF! error when coping a formula using this trick to a different row.  So the answer should read `$1:$1048576` and `$1:$65536`

Answer (score 6):

A quick hack is to click the space above the intersection between first row & first column when prompted for a range to apply to

[image]